# Firebase, web application: get documents by user

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying Firebase on my web project and I wonder how to get data from Firestore by currently logged user.

I was trying something like this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
```

```
firebase.firestore().collection('posts').add({
        title: this.title,
        content: this.content,
        user: uid
})
```

```
firebase.firestore().collection('posts').where("user", "==", uid).get()
    .then(snapshots => {
      this.posts = snapshots.docs.map(doc => {
        const data = doc.data();
        return {
          id: doc.id,
          title: data.title,
          content: data.content
        }
      })
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error.message);
    });
```

What works well, but it doesn't look very 'professional', so I just wonder if there is any proper way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO your code looks fine and readable – don't attempt to be 'professional' if that equals fancy. The take below is just one man's opinion of using variables a bit more :)

```
const db = firebase         
    .initializeApp({ 
        // config ...
    }) 
    .firestore();

const auth = firebase.auth();
const user = auth.currentUser.uid;

const postRef = db.collection('posts');

//  add 
const { title, content } = this;
postRef
    .add({
        title,
        content,
        user
    })

//  get 
postRef
    .where('user', '==', user)
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        this.posts = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }))  
    })
    .catch(console.error)
```

Comment: I assume you like all post data + ID

Answer (score 2):

use isEqualTo as shown below:

where("user", isEqualTo: uid).get()